# Looking for HP fanfic: Powerful Harry, because basilisk-venom and phoenix-tears battle and strengthen his core

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction story.  I probably read it on AO3, though it's possible it was in FFN or maybe even some other site.  I don't really remember any details, so it'll probably be hard to match, but here goes...

It's a very-powerful-Harry-Potter kind of fic, the interesting is why he's powerful - and this is pretty much the detail I remember...  Since after the end of CoS, Harry has had basilisk-venom (possibly from a tooth still embedded in his body) and phoenix-tears constantly battling each other inside his body, and this has caused his magical-core to grow beyond all reason.

I don't remember if Harry is an adult or still at Hogwarts, but if he still is at Hogwarts, it must be during his final few years, since the venom-tears must have had time to strengthen his core.

Comment: We really need more details. I plugged in the search terms and came up with a page of fanfics that use that premise...

Comment: What is a "magical core"? I don't remember that from canon...

Comment: @Kevin Very much used in fanfic - one way or the other.  It's the reservoir inside a witch or wizard were their magic comes from.  In fanfic the magic core often grows or get filled, and they often may have to meditate or visualize their core to access more magic.

Answer (score 6):

Just throwing one out there, "[Harry Potter and the Wandless Magic](https://www.wattpad.com/382907621-harry-potter-and-the-wandless-magic-chapter-one)"

> When Harry was bitten by the Basilisk, the venom destroyed the Horcrux in his head, but Fawkes saved Harry's life. The venom and phoenix tears combined break the seal on Harry's magical core. Accidental magic begins to happen around him, and not all...

Answer (score 4):

The rest doesn't match up, and says nothing about "enlarging him magical core" but in the now famous [*Make a Wish*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2318355/1/Make-A-Wish) by Rorschach's Blot has Harry (Mr Black) having lethal blood while being immune to most poisons because he has a chip of basilisk fang still embedded in the bone of his arm and the Phoenix tears have remained in his system. He also ends up being bitten by a werewolf, ingesting vampire blood and absorbing some [yuki-onna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki-onna) power when getting a magical tattoo, drinking [re'em blood](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Re%27em_blood) ... He also becomes quite powerful during the the story.

Comment: It certainly sounds like this could be a match. Does it mention anything about the various poisons and substances interacting with each other?

Comment: Well, he didn't turn into a were or a vamp, but did get greater physical strength and improved senses as well as retractable fangs. After the yuki-onna bit he got improved resistance to cold and some white strands in his hair and also better control over weather magic. The re'em blood gave a further strength increase. I haven't read it in a while, but I know he also got taller, healed faster, etc. at some point and his eyes changed colour. Can't remember everything that happened to change him, but by the end of the story he had to wear an enchanted bracelet to look "like Harry Potter"

Comment: Getting some major Bleach vibes

Comment: *snigger* well Rorshach's Blot has all sorts of very cracky stories and Make a Wish is a trope miner's lucky strike, so Bleach may even feature in there somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

[Deadly Eyes of a Phoenix Reborn](https://archiveofourown.org/works/2517824/chapters/5593526) by Watermelonsmellinfellon has the same sort of summary you mentioned.

> In the summer after his second year, something unexpected happens to
> Harry. Changes are occurring, though he doesn't know it. What will he
> do when he realizes that the Basilisk venom and the Phoenix tears are
> turning him into something new entirely? How will this change the
> outcome against Voldemort? What will happen?

I haven't read it but it seems quite similar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).